# Dynamic binding with constructor

Tags: java, dynamic, binding, constructor

I am a bit confused with the binding type of a constructor.
Why is calling

`Canvas c = new Circle();` not dynamic binding?

Thank you!

Comment: see here about static binding and dynamic binding - http://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/java-static-dynamic-binding/

Comment: Because it is absolutely and explicitly clear *at compile time* that a certain constructor of class Circle is being called.

Comment: http://javaconceptoftheday.com/static-binding-and-dynamic-binding-in-java/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is static binding as it is done during compile time.

If class Circle has a method that overrides a method from Canvas and you call that method like the following, then it is called dynamic binding.

```
//if you override some method in the child class that is Circle 
c.someMethod() //example of dynamic binding
```

You can read [static vs dynamic](http://javaconceptoftheday.com/static-binding-and-dynamic-binding-in-java/) for more.